# The partitioning of a big disk is necessary for LVM's vg space expansion

Tags: lvm, partition, raid1

I am maintaining a LVM's vg as users' /home directory's storage space. But now I need to add a new 2T sized disk for extending the /home space. I wonder if the partitioning is necessary or not and then I use the several partitions as physical volumes. I prefer to use the entire disk as a physical volume member of the existing vg group for /home. Anyway I have known that multi-partition will make a disaster within a partition. By the way I must mention that both the /home space thant is existing and the 2T space I am adding are on the LSI raid raid-1 mirrored disks.

I know that the decision is really depending on the quality of disks, raid arrangement and experiences. I only hope experienced engineers can review this case and see how other engineer are doing for this case.

Cheers!

Comment: You appear to be considering only "use `/dev/sda`" and "use `/dev/sda[123...]`".  HBrujin, below, adds the middle ground of "use `/dev/sda1`" (ie, a single partition that covers the whole HDD), and that's what I'd suggest, too (+1 from me, HBrujin!).

Answer (score 2):

LVM supports using the whole disk , without a partition table, for use as LVM physical volume. (The same holds true for SAN and iSCSI LUN's etc.)

Normally I still recommend creating the partition table because:

- a partition table prevents other (non-Linux) systems from seeing the disk volume as raw/un-partitioned free space.

That may not be a risk in your environment, but since there's no penalty in doing so, I think it's a good habit to maintain.

Then I would simply create 1 large partition (with label `8e` for Linux LVM) spanning the whole disk when the additional new space will be assigned to a single volume group. When two different volume groups need expanding, then you'll need (at least) two partitions.

---

In your case you have a RAID controller with two mirrored drives.

If you circumvent the RAID controller and add the single drive to the volume group providing space for /home you're losing redundancy, if that single disk fails, you'll **lose all data** on `/home/`.

Typically, it easier and better to get two new drives, set up mirroring for those two in your RAID controller and only then add the space to your volume group.

If you can't get two  new disks, you can still change the RAID level in your controller, effectively going from RAID1 to RAID5, maintaining redundancy,  but most controllers don't have that as an online non-destructive option. Doing so means backing up all data, rebuilding the RAID volume and then restore everything.

Comment: Thanks! I will give the two partitions to the mirrored disk and then assigned them to the vg group  in which /home lg is staying. The partitioning here is only providing flexibility to future space reallocation. For data safty, I must be depending on the raid setup and baking up more than 2 times in differenct places